# SitecoreContext throwing error after Sitecore upgrade

Tags: glass-mapper

I upgraded my dev instance from `Sitecore 8.2` to `Sitecore 9.3`.

My upgrade was successful but I am getting errors when I am trying to access my page.

In our solution for getting the current page, we are using `SitecoreContext`.

Here my code:

```
var currentPage = SitecoreContext.GetCurrentItem<BasePage>();
```

and by using this code on the page I am getting the error, shown in below screenshot

[image]

We are using the following glass mapper version

```
<package id="Glass.Mapper.Sc.93.Core" version="5.8.171" targetFramework="net48" />
<package id="Glass.Mapper.Sc.93.Mvc" version="5.8.171" targetFramework="net48" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I can see you are using GlassMapper 5 version and in GlassMapper 5 version **SitecoreContext**, **GlassView**, **GlassController** are obsolete. On behalf of **SitecoreContext** you can `Use either IRequestContext, IMvcContext or IWebFormsContext`.

Or you can use **SitecoreContext** as well, by initializing it first then use it.

```
var objSitecoreContext = new SitecoreContext();
var currentPage = objSitecoreContext.GetCurrentItem<BasePage>();
```

It will work for you.

Answer (score 3):

`GlassMapper` functionality was removed from 5.x `SitecoreContext`. That's why you cannot call `sitecoreContext.GetItem` anymore. According to Glass Mapper documenation (link below):

```
sitecoreContext.GetItem
```

should be replaced with

```
mvcContext.SitecoreService.GetItem
```

Here you can read about other tips & tricks for upgrading from v4 to v5:

https://gerhartmagdas.wordpress.com/2021/03/24/sitecore-upgrade-journey-part-2/